# How to route a specific JSP using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I have the code below and need to redirect it to a different JSP if the service is success

```
                $scope.User = $resource('anc/validUser', data)
            .get().$promise.then(
                    function(response){
                        console.log('success');
                        $location.path('/home');
                    }, function() {
                        console.log('error');
                    });
```

I was using $location and I am not sure if that is a valid one. Can someone guide me to understand how to route to a different JSP. I have a login.jsp and after the authentication validation through a REST service, I need to take the user to home.jsp

Comment: Then use $location.path('/home.jsp'); And in controller you have to define $location

Comment: I tried but the path has a hash in it. I am not sure if I have to change the relative path in JS or ?
Ssystems/#/home.jsp

How should I mention the relative path in ANgularJS. I have defined the application context root in my JSP using <base> tag

Comment: You can try scope.$apply(function() { $location.path("/home"); });

Comment: It didn't help though. I am not sure why do I get a # in middle of my URL and also whether the ViewResolver will be playing any role in determining the path.
I have all my JSP's under webapp:WEB-INF:views